# Empty routes in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to register a simple method into a [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and I'm having some problems. The **route is not showing** in API Explorer.

It's probably something simple that I'm missing..
How can I get the register route to show in the API?

> Resuts (empty)

```
GET /api/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{}
```

> Urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token

from reservations.views.homepage import HomepageView
from users.views import UserViewSet

""" API routes
"""
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'test', UserViewSet, base_name='users')

""" Route patterns
"""
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomepageView.as_view(), name='homepage'),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

> Viewset

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def register(self, request):
        return Response({
            'status': 'User registered'
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewSet has some specific methods for every method (GET, POST, PUT etc) like list, detail, create, update etc. You should use that methods. Api explorer decides on the basis of these methods that which method is allowed by your view. You can see these methods [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/).

In your case, I suppose you want to create new user. So you should use create method like this.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({
            'status': 'User registered'
        })
```

Comment: thanks! Does that mean that if I want to have an URL something like `test/register` I have to register a whole ViewSet to it with just one method?(in my case create) and then if i want to have something like `test/create` I'd have to add another ViewSet because I've already overwritten the `create` method in previous ViewSet. That means two ViewSets and two routes registered just for 2 methods? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work only with then list, create method you must have in it. Please check below example of my code. please check this link for more information http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = crm_models.EmployeeLeaveApp.objects.all()
        serializer = serializers.EmployeeVisitSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = crm_models.EmployeeLeaveApp.objects.all()
        user = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = serializers.EmployeeVisitSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)


    def list(self, request):
        pass

    def create(self, request):
        pass

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        pass
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to use GenericViews, also I'm curious why the current approach isn't working and not so much in an alternatives. Thanks aynway!

Answer (score 1):

Use @list_route for this. [marking extra actions for routing](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

```
...

@list_route(methods=['post'])
def register(self, request):
    return Response({
        'status': 'User registered'
    })
```